# Why I cannot use if or switch on jSONObject?

Tags: android, if-statement, android-asynctask, switch-statement

I simply have an **AsyncTask** that **use a listener to communicate with the main activity**. Where the response is arrived , and the first Toast will been shown with correct values. The problem is that in **try catch** I can recover the values. So if or switch don't work anymore.

```
@Override
public void OnAsyncTaskComplete(String response) {

    Toast.makeText(getContext(),((ActivityLogin) getActivity()).choiceButton+" result: "+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

        String objservice = obj.getString("service");
        String objstatuCode = obj.getString("status-code");
        String objdescription = obj.getString("status-description");

        JSONObject result = obj.getJSONObject("result");

        if(!objstatuCode.equals("200") || objstatuCode.equals(null)){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), objstatuCode+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), objstatuCode+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: share your json response with question

Comment: share response here

Comment: first of all swap your condition like this, if(objstatuCode.equals(null) || !objstatuCode.equals("200") ){} and your status code is integer use getInt

Comment: not working its the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, You getting [**`JSONException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONException).

**Why?**

```
Thrown to indicate a problem with the JSON API
```

**Problem coming from**

```
 String objstatuCode = obj.getString("status-code");
 JSONObject result = obj.getJSONObject("result");
```

Your **`JSON VALUE (KEY=status-code)`** is **`int`**. You should rectify that.

It must be

```
int objstatuCode = obj.getInt("status-code");
String result    = obj.getString("result");
```

Then

```
if(objstatuCode!=200){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), objstatuCode+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), objstatuCode+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
```

Comment: @GiorgioCafiso Clean-Rebuild and let me inform.

Comment: solved thx man. the mistakes was i hve other call in the same achivities where result was an array

Comment: @GiorgioCafiso Move ahead!